# How to change items or things in the pouch?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I'm playing Zelda - Skyward sword. I can't change items or things from my pouch or items collection. When I'm on the "item menu" I do as I'm told - I press and hold B to select, but the moment I let go all I get is a description of the item :( What do I do wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to rearrange the position of items?

Comment: Try rewording your question.  The word "change" is somewhat ambiguous in this context.  Do you mean "swap" (add items/remove items to/from storage in Skyloft), or do you mean "reorganize" (change position/orientation of items currently in pouch)?

Answer (score 8):

What you're currently doing is viewing your inventory. What you need to do is either press and hold <kbd>B</kbd> to open up your "tools" pouch (slingshot, beetle, etc.) or press and hold the <kbd>-</kbd> button until your pouch containing your shield and bottles and whatnot opens. Then, still holding the <kbd>-</kbd> button, you can select the item you want.

If you want to move things around in your adventure pouch, you need to go see Peatrice at the Item check in the Bazaar in Skyloft. She will let you reorder the items in your pouch and let you pull things out as well.

You cannot, however, change any item in your collections or tool pouch.

Comment: ive tried all your suggestions and nothing works.......I feel like breaking the wiimote!!!!

Comment: @KEm: I've played the game plenty, and Kareen's instructions are pretty much spot-on. Are you trying to do things from *within* the inventory screen (the one that takes up the whole screen and pauses the game)? If so, you need to close it, and then follow Kareen's instructions (hold the button, aim the wiimote) from the normal screen.

Answer (score 4):

To use an item, quickly hit <kbd>B</kbd> to equip it,  then use it with <kbd>A</kbd>. Holding down <kbd>B</kbd> will let you choose an item.

Likewise, quickly press <kbd>-</kbd> to equip an item from your adventure pouch (usually a potion), then hit <kbd>A</kbd> to use. Hold <kbd>-</kbd> to choose an item from your adventure pouch.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should be able to pick up an item with the A button and hold it down to drag it into the pouch.

I think that what I did last night anyways.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the "Cursed Medal" you can't open your pouch.

Comment: Maybe this is a comment instead of a question?  The OP doesn't specifically mention having the cursed medal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are carrying a cursed medal, then you are not able access anything in your pouch: totally frustrating, took me hours to figure that out!