# How do I equip a bottle, and re-equip 2nd & 3rd bottle?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I can't even get the shield to equip much less the bottles.  I have no trouble on the slingshot, blower or whip -those all work normally.

Could I get a basic step by step instruction for this?  I replaced the new motion controller because I thought it had a problem.  Second motion controller works the same.  I have one of the first Wiis to come out.

Comment: See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/44200/7091

Answer (score 6):

For bottles and shields, use the <kbd>-</kbd> button to equip them, not <kbd>B</kbd> like you do for the various tools like the slingshot and whip. But the process is the same; hold <kbd>-</kbd>, point at the thing you want, then release <kbd>-</kbd> and Link will get out whatever you pointed at (well, not medals or extra seed/bomb/arrow bags, they just take up space). Press <kbd>A</kbd> to drink from a bottle once Link has it out.

Comment: @J.B.Vaughan - If this answer solved your problem, you should [accept it](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask), by clicking the check-mark to the left of the text. This is helpful for future searchers, and also rewards the answerer (and you!).